# Redirect loop problem in IIS on shared hosting

Tags: iis, redirect, loops, shared-hosting

I have a problem where when I go to my website it comes up with a redirect loop.  I've tried clearing the URL Redirects from the IIS Admin Console in the web control panel from my hosting provider and I've also tried removing the httpd.ini file from the site root directory to try and clear all re-directs, but for some reason when I go to the site it STILL wants to redirect in an endless loop.   The site is   agrionline.biz

Before i did anything I had a subdirectory domain pointing set up which made http://agrionline.biz actually use agrionline.biz/site1/ as the root folder.
I wanted to change this so that instead of that I wanted my site to actually redirect to the site1 folder, rather than use it as the root.  So I went into the IIS Admin Console on my hosting providers web control panel and tried to add a URL Redirect from '/'  to  '/site1/'.  Then i went to the domain pointing admin page in the hosting providers web control panel and deleted the domain pointing. Anyway after doing all this, the site is now stuffed and if I go to back to both these areas and clear the redirects and the domain pointing and even go and remove the httpd.ini file that was created, the site still incorrectly re-directs!

What can I do to resolve this? Any ideas? Has anyone experienced this before on a shared hosting account without direct access to IIS.

From the control panel it says my server platform is Windows 2008 Server Enterprise.

Comment: Have you checked that maybe it was a permanent redirect, I don't remember what series in 300 that is, and it might now be cached for you now?

Comment: Hmm I definitely didn't tick the 'permanent redirect' option when I added it, so no, i don't think it was a permanent redirect.... but i didn't think to check that though....